# Contains() not working with query string that contains forward slash in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement a search function in my website that can search by date. It is a wildcard search, meaning the user can input anything and it will search multiple fields in the database.

An example URL is `testsite.com/Note/SearchNotes?searchquery=6/27`. And I have a record in the database with value `6/27/2022 5:44:24 PM` in the `DateCreated` column.

```
public ActionResult SearchNotes(string searchquery)
{
    var test = db.Notes.Where(Note => Note.DateCreated.ToString().Contains(searchquery) 
    || /* check more properties */).ToList(); //returns 0
}
```

My problem is it is not returning any data when a query string such as `"6/27"` contains a forward slash. A string like `"27"` does return data. I believe `/` is a legal character, so I can't see why I am facing this problem.

One observation: it may be related to `ToString()` because forward slashes are returning data on properties that are already of type `string`.

Could anyone explain the reason for this behavior? Or better yet a solution?

Comment: Use URL encoding and decoding to pass special characters in a query string

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint and examined the value of `searchquery`? Just wondering if it's getting encoded correctly, since forward slashes are special characters in url strings.

Comment: Yes I have set a breakpoint and `searchquery` is exactly as it is in the url. Also I have another column called Comments that returns data when I run this `db.Notes.Where(Note => Note.Comments.Contains(searchquery)`. Again making me think the url is fine.

Comment: @DanielMann, Rufus L Also I just tried using `%2F` instead of the slash, with the same results.

Comment: @cytech04 That's **encoding** it. Are you **decoding** it? Are you confirming in a debugger that the value that's arriving in your controller actually matches what you expect it to?

Comment: @DanielMann Yes it definitely is. `searchquery = 6/27` inside the controller action. I even tried manually setting `searchquery = "6/27"` inside the action. It is still returning 0.

Comment: @cytech04 Did you check DateCreated.ToString() ? it could be  06-27-2022 ...

Comment: @cytech04: Check what the `Note.DateCreated.ToString()` returns. The issue might be related to the localization in case client and server uses different locale. On the server the date after converting to a string might be in dd/MM/yyyy format or uses `-` character instead of `/`. Perhaps it's necessary to use `DateCreated.ToString()` and provide correct [CultureInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=netframework-4.8) format, by using `HttpRequest.UserLanguages` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime.TryParse(@"6/27/2022 5:44:24 PM", out var dateCreated);
var notes = new List<string>
{
  @"testsite.com/Note/SearchNotes?searchquery=6/27"
  , @"Some Other Data"
  , @"someOtherNote containing 27..."
  , dateCreated.ToString()
  , dateCreated.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd")
  , dateCreated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
  , dateCreated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
};
Console.WriteLine("test1");
var test = notes.Where(note => note.Contains("27")).ToList();
foreach (var result in test)
  Console.WriteLine(result);;
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine("test2");
var test2 = notes.Where(note => note.Contains("/27")).ToList();
foreach (var result in test2)
  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

produces

```
test1
testsite.com/Note/SearchNotes?searchquery=6/27
someOtherNote containing 27...
2022-06-27 17:44:24
2022-06-27
06-27-2022
06/27/2022

test2
testsite.com/Note/SearchNotes?searchquery=6/27
06/27/2022
```

which I think answers your question.  DateTime formatting, culture, machine- and user-regional environment settings / localization is all a bit of dark art and to be sure that you find date (parts) by string-matching you must be sure to match format.

Note that even the explicit format "MM/dd/yyyy" produced output formatted "MM-dd-yyyy" until I specified `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Comment: Thanks @AlanK. That nails it. Lesson learned again, don't assume! But I have a new problem now. To give `ToString()` an overload like that I have to use `Note.DateCreated.Value.ToString(...)` because `DateCreated` is nullable. But that throws the errror that `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method System.String, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` This may be a topic for another discussion. Just wondering if you knew any "easy" fix.

Comment: You're welcome and that is an old problem (which I failed to spot).  LINQ to Entities has to translate to SQL and String.Format() doesn't map.  I can't test this for you but there's a trick that requires converting the query result to IEnumerable, something like `db.Notes.AsEnumerable.Where...`.  Google is your friend on this one, just search for the error text.

Comment: Ok. I have seen that but have also heard that is not good practice as it pulls the whole db and then filters it after the SQL query. So complicated. Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed.  If you control the DB, try store dates as (N)(VAR)CHAR.  Space penalty but then you control the storage format.  If this sort of query is a key feature you're in for performance trouble anyway because the conditionals will force full table scans.  I once had a similar "scan all columns" problem and ended up creating a parallel table with two columns - key into a parent table followed by concatenation of all of its columns I needed to search.  Full table scans still happen but over only one column that links directly back to original data. Good luck.